# php Timestamp working logic

Tags: php, datetime

what is exactly happing when creating a Unix Timestamp from a given date.

I want the step by step method to create timestamp. (not using php built in functions).

**EDIT:** What is the specialty of this date :) **January 1st 1970 00:00 h UTC**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

January 1st 1970 00:00 h UTC is the date of the [Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) :

> The "epoch" then serves as a reference
>   point from which time is measured.
>   Time measurement units are counted
>   from the epoch so that the date and
>   time of events can be specified
>   unambiguously.

In [computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing), this date is the Epoch for UNIX time : UNIX timestamps *(as used by PHP)* are actually the number of seconds since that Epoch.

This means that, to create a timestamp, you have to count how many seconds have passed since the 1st January 1970.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to count the seconds that elapsed from January 1st 1970 00:00 h UTC until now (not counting leap seconds)!